# In Parshas Chukas, why is first mention of Parah Adumah "פָרָה" instead of "פָּרָה"?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, vowels-nekudot, chukas, parah-adumah

The first mention of the Parah Adumah in Parshas Chukas ([Numbers 19:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.19.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) is:

> דַּבֵּ֣ר  אֶל־בְּנֵ֣י יִשְׂרָאֵ֗ל וְיִקְח֣וּ אֵלֶיךָ֩ פָרָ֨ה אֲדֻמָּ֜ה
>
> Instruct the people of Israel to bring you a red cow without blemish

There "פָרָה" is without a *dagesh* (dot inside) and is pronounced with an "**F**" sound- "farrah."

However, in describing the rest of the procedure the Torah uses "פָּרָה" ***with*** a *dagesh*, pronounced as "parah" with a hard "**P**" sound (see [19:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.19.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [19:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.19.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) [19:9](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.19.9?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en), [19:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.19.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

**Question:**
Why is the first mention of the Parah Adumah "פָרָה" instead of  "פָּרָה"?

Answer (score 7):

Generally, when a word ends in a vowel sound, without a pausal cantillation note on that word, the first letter in the next word loses its *dagesh*. Usually, the rule is stated in terms of the previous word ending with one of the letters אהוי, but here, it seems to be operating on the previous word's last consonant being succeeded in pronunciation by a vowel. It's probably smoother to pronounce a fricative (non-*dagesh*) consonant right after a vowel sound than a harder consonant.

Source: High school Biblical grammar class. These rules are written up in books, but none of those books are ultimately the source for the rules, as they're all based ultimately on observing patterns in the Torah itself.

Comment: This isn't the first time on this site someone has had to explain basic biblical begedkefet rules. Do we really need a new question for every word? Is there not a sufficient duplicate already? Or can we make a sufficiently canonical one?

Comment: @DoubleAA If there's another question that is an instance of the same אהוי rule, I think it would be fair to dupe them.

Comment: @Heshy, Actually, it was a happy accident of circumstance. My state mandated two years of foreign language class, which my (very small) school fulfilled with Modern Hebrew. Before my second year, the teacher they had lined up for this class quit, so, in a pinch, the principal / rabbi taught the class instead. He was interested in *dikduk*, so we spent the year pretty much learning the *dikduk* comments in Rashi.

Comment: @DoubleAA OTOH, this one is an אהוי question without the [apparent] presence of אהוי, so it's a little special. I guess it would be helpful to have a question asking "In the Torah, when does the first letter of a word get a dagesh, and when doesn't it?" A comprehensive-enough answer to that would probably be short of book-length and could be a helpful dupe-target.

Comment: Note that it's not 100% clear that the Telisha Ketana is not a (partially) pausal sound, see here: http://parsha.blogspot.com/2011/06/fricative-feh-in-and-more-minchas-shai.html

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I encourage you or joshwaxman to write up a more informative answer based on that post.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I'm not sure I agree with R' Josh's analysis of those chumashim.  They could be following Ben Naftali, but maybe they're just treating it as אתי מרחיק

Comment: @IsaacMoses it's academic anyways. This is how we read it, and your answer addresses why we read it that way...

Comment: @Heshy, or it's just a mistake, or it didn't say that at all... There can be many suggestions, and we don't know why. My guess is if you looked up other similar cases, you would not find them following Ben Naftali, but I'll leave that to you...

Comment: @IsaacMoses https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/34283/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/91766/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/64588/759 https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/70721/759